# Is there an analytic function with $f(1/n)=a_n \text{ where } a_n \in \{1/2,0,1/4,0,1/6 \ldots\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there an analytic function such that

$$f(1/n)=a_n \text{ where } a_n \in \{1/2,0,1/4,0,1/6 \ldots\}\text?$$

I could not solve this problem. Perhaps I am missing some lemma not shown in class.

Thank you.

Comment: The [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) is a useful theorem for problems like this. To get you started: try to come up with an analytic function $g(z)$ such that $g(a_n) = f(a_n)$. Writing $f(1/n) = \frac{1 - \cos(\pi n)}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}$ might be useful for this purpose.

Comment: Correction: it should read $g(1/n) = f(1/n)$ above not $g(a_n) = f(a_n)$. Also it might be easier to consider the sequence $a_{2n}$ and find an analytical function where $g(1/2n) = f(1/2n)$.

Comment: Does $f$ have to be defined in $0$?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is stated that way, you can pick $a_n$ to be a constant sequence in that set (in which case the repetitions of elements in the set make no sense). It is easy to come up with an entire function which is a fixed constant at many points.

If $a_n$ is the listed sequence, then here is a hint:

**Hint**
$$f(\frac{1}{2n})=0$$

The identity theorem tells you exactly what $f$ is, and that choice contradicts the other values of $f$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a function. For $0<|z|<1$ define

$$f(z) = \frac{z\sin^2(\pi/(2z))}{z+1}.$$

Then $f$ is analytic in $\{0<|z|<1\}$ and $f(1/n) = a_n$ for all $n.$

Comment: The point is that you didn't specify where the function has to be analytic.